# Work with both JSP (no Facelets) and JSF, how I config my web.xml?

Tags: java, jsf, web.xml

I really need help, I'm new with JSF, actually I'm trying to implement in a project that uses jsp(NO FACES) some new applications that works with JSF, both jsp and jsf works fine if I change my faces config file, the problem its the view handler of faces

```xml
<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

How can I change my web.xml so it can use faces config only to my new applications?

Comment: Which version and implementation of JSF are you using?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the Facelets view handler if you don't need Facelets?

Comment: I'm using jsf 1.2 because its over websphere 6...

Comment: Because I use facelets in the new applications that uses JSF...the old applications doesnt have to use the faces config....